# Format a Resource string into another one?

Tags: c#, resources

What would be the best way to accomplish something like this?

Suppose I have the following pair of `Resource` strings.

```
BadRequestParameter:            Potential bad request aborted before execution.
RequiredParameterConstraint:    {0} parameter requires a value. {1}
```

And suppose I want to set `{1}` on the second one, to the value of `BadRequestParameter`. I could easily do that using `string.Format`. But now suppose I have lots of `Resource` strings like the second one, all of which include some other `Resource` string in them.
 What would be the best way to code this? Is using `string.Format` repeateadly in each case really all that I can do?

**Update**

I'll try to explain myself better. These are the resource strings I actually have:

```
BadRequestParameter     Potential bad request aborted before execution. 
EmptyVector             Vectorized requests require at least one element. {0}
OverflownVector         Vectorized requests can take at most one hundred elements. {0}
RequiredParamConstraint {0} parameter requires a value. {1}
SortMinMaxConstraint    {0} parameter value '{1}' does not allow Min or Max parameters in this query. {2}
SortRangeTypeConstraint Expected {0} parameter Type '{1}'. Actual: '{2}'. {3}
SortValueConstraint     {0} parameter does not allow '{1}' as a value in this query. {2}
```

I'd like to avoid writing the string in `BadRequestParameter` at the end of each of those lines. Therefore, I added a format at the end of those strings. The issue now is that I'd like to somehow auto-reference `{x}` to `BadRequestParameter`, in order to avoid having to make calls like

```
string.Format(Error.EmptyVector, Error.BadRequestParameter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have lots of Resource strings like the second one, all of which include some other Resource string in them.

Instead of storing pre-made format strings ready for use, you could store raw material for building real format strings, and add code to expand them pro grammatically before use. For example, you could store strings like this:

```
BadRequestParameter:            Potential bad request aborted before execution.
SupportNumber:                  (123)456-7890
CallTechSupport:                You need to call technical support at {SupportNumber}.
RequiredParameterConstraint:    {{0}} parameter requires a value. {BadRequestParameter} {CallTechSupport}
```

Of course passing these strings to `string.Format` as-is is not going to work. You need to parse these strings, for example with `RegExp`s, and find all instances where you have a word between curly braces, instead of a number. You could then replace each word with its sequence number, and produce an array of parameters based on the names that you find between curly braces. In this case, you will get these two values (pseudocode):

```
formatString = "{{0}} parameter requires a value. {0} {1}";
// You replaced {BadRequestParameter} with {0} and {CallTechSupport} with {1}
parameters = {
    "Potential bad request aborted before execution."
,   "You need to call technical support at (123)456-7890."
};
```

**Note:** Of course, producing this array of `parameters` required recursion.

At this point, you can invoke `string.Format` to produce your final string:

```
var res = string.Format(formatString, parameters);
```

This returns the string that has resource strings pre-replaced for your callers:

```
"{0} parameter requires a value. Potential bad request aborted before execution. You need to call technical support at (123)456-7890."
```

The callers can now use this string for formatting, without bothering with other resource values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes :-) unless you want to make a helper method that is shorter, but that would really just be for convenience sake

```
public static string f(string format, params object[] p)
{
    return string.Format(format, p);
}
```

Comment: I do use a `.FormatWith()` extension method, for sugar, but that's besides the question.

Comment: what's so bad about it? of little value I could agree with, but if he wants to type 5 less letters, that's his business.

Answer (score 0):

IF you treat the argument indicators `{#}` as wild cards then why would it make sense for you to pre-fill them inside of your resource.

I see absolutely nothing wrong with

```
String.Format(RequiredParamterConstraint, "something", BadRequestParameter);
```

Comment: Because I'll be repeating myself a lot, almost a dozen of resources have `BadRequestParameter` as a format argument, this could also introduce bugs (having to manually position the argument instead of somehow auto-applying it).

Comment: That's the whole point of string.format and resources. I don't see how it's going to introduces any more bugs than a complicated piece of logic to do that for you.